# Is $(x^n)$ decreasing if and only if $x\in(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I was reading something where one of the steps said $x\leqslant-1\implies x^{4}\geqslant x^{2}$. I stopped and thought on this part about $x^{4}$ being greater than or equal to $x^{2}$. In the case of $x>1$, I could believe that powers of this number would get bigger and bigger, while, for example, if it's something like $\frac{1}{2}$, then powers of it take halves and make the number smaller. I reckoned then that these $x^{n}$s only got smaller if $-1<x<1$.

So I thought maybe we can claim $(x^n)$ is decreasing if and only if $x\in(0,1)$, but wasn't totally sure how I would prove this.

Comment: Consider $$(\frac12)^{x}=2^{-x}$$ and relate this to what you know about transformations of monotonic functions

Comment: It probably said $x \leq -1$

Comment: What do you know about first derivative test?

Comment: But if $x<-1$, you still have $\;\dots <x^5<x^3<<x<x^2<x^4 <x^6<\dots$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what transformations of monotonic functions means . . . (Maybe I should mention that I'm just a schmuck self-learning so I don't really know all the things one might reasonably expect someone asking this question to know.) I know the first derivative is $nx^{n-1}$. This is zero at $x=0$. But then if we test points to the right, then I get positive numbers, so function is increasing if $x>0$? . . .

Comment: $x^{n+1}= x^n*x$.  If $0< x< 1$ then $x^n*x < x^n*1$.... if $x\ge 1$ then $x^n*x \ge x^n*1$.  If $x \le 0$ well.... flip-flop time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < x < 1$ then use the axiom:  If $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.

So $0< x < 1$ so $0*x < x*x < 1*x$ so $0 < x^2 < x< 1$ and by induction if you have $0 < x^n < x^{n-1}$ you have $0*x < x^n*x <x^{n-1}x $ so $0< x^{n+1}< x^n$.

So $x^n$ is decreasing.  (which *doesn't* prove $x^n\to 0$ FWIW.)

Now if $x \in (0,1)$ we have.

$x < 0$:  Well then $x^n > 0$ if $n$ is even and $x^n < 0$ if $n$ is odd.  So that's not decreasing.

$x = 0$:  Well then $x^n = 0^n = 0$ which constant; not decreasing.

$x =1$: Well then $x^n =1^n=1$ which ...ditto...

$x> 1$ then by similar induction $1 < x$ so $1*x < x*x$ and if $1 < x^n$ then $1 < x \implies x^n < x*x^n=x^{n+1}$ so $x^n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(x^n)$ is decreasing for $(0,1)$. You can prove this by extending $n$ to a continuous variable $y$, i.e. $$f(y) = x^y,\qquad  x > 0 $$ and note that $f'(y) = x^y \ln x$  is negative for $x\in (0,1)$.

For $x < 0$ you can always prove that the sequence is alternating, since $x^n < x^{n + 1}$ implies $x^{n+1} > x^{n + 2}$ by multiplying by $x$.